# Convertir metodo recursivo a no recursivo

Tags: java

tengo una duda con una practica. Tengo un metodo recursivo realizado pero me gustaria hacerlo sin la recursion, ¿alguien sabria hacerlo?
El metodo es este:

```
public int length(PositionList<Vertex<V>> path) {
        return lengthRec(path, path.first(), 0); 
    }

    private int lengthRec(PositionList<Vertex<V>> path, Position<Vertex<V>> vert, int suma){
        Position<Vertex<V>> next = path.next(vert);
        if(vert.equals(path.last())) return suma; 
        Iterator<Edge<Integer>> it = graph.outgoingEdges(vert.element()).iterator(); 
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Edge<Integer> edge = it.next(); 
            if(graph.endVertex(edge).equals(next.element())) {
                int result = edge.element() + lengthRec(path, path.next(vert), suma); ; 
                if(result!=0) return result; 
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Qué has probado hasta ahora? ¿Has intentado algún método convencional de conversión (por ejemplo, usando pilas)?

Comment: Hola, es que nos obligan a usar grafos

Comment: Me refiero a usar una pila para almacenar resultados intermedios en el algoritmo iterativo. Es la solución más sencilla. No me refiero a usar una pila en lugar de un grafo en los datos de entrada del problema. Imagino que no os habrán limitado la manera de convertir de un método a otro.

Comment: No, no nos han limitado las formas de convertirlo. Pero no entiendo muy bien lo que me dices, ¿podrias convertir este o ponerme un ejemplo?

Comment: Claro, aquí tienes unos ejemplos: [http://haacked.com/archive/2007/03/04/Replacing_Recursion_With_a_Stack.aspx/](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/03/04/Replacing_Recursion_With_a_Stack.aspx/), [https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/418776/How-to-replace-recursive-functions-using-stack-and](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/418776/How-to-replace-recursive-functions-using-stack-and), [https://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceRecursionWithIteration.html](https://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceRecursionWithIteration.html), etc.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Convertir metodo recursivo en uno no recursivo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/502988/convertir-metodo-recursivo-en-uno-no-recursivo)