# Convertir metodo recursivo en uno no recursivo

Tags: java

tengo una duda con una practica. Ha de realizarse con grafos obligatoriamente pero no entiendo mucho de ellos. He logrado sacar un metodo recursivo pero me gustaria hacerlo sin la recursion, ¿alguien sabria hacerlo? El metodo es este:

```
// Return the length of a path in the graph.
// The path has to have at least one node.
public int length(PositionList<Vertex<V>> path) {
        return lengthRec(path, path.first(), 0); 
    }

    private int lengthRec(PositionList<Vertex<V>> path, Position<Vertex<V>> vert, int suma){
        Position<Vertex<V>> next = path.next(vert);
        if(vert.equals(path.last())) return suma; 
        Iterator<Edge<Integer>> it = graph.outgoingEdges(vert.element()).iterator(); 
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Edge<Integer> edge = it.next(); 
            if(graph.endVertex(edge).equals(next.element())) {
                int result = edge.element() + lengthRec(path, path.next(vert), suma); ; 
                if(result!=0) return result; 
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Toda ayuda es bienvenida, muchas gracias.

Comment: Esta pregunta se puede rehacer como "tengo este ejercicio, hacédmelo". No es el objetivo de SOes. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] y edites tu pregunta añadiendo qué has intentado y qué es lo que te bloquea

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Convertir metodo recursivo a no recursivo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/502983/convertir-metodo-recursivo-a-no-recursivo)

Comment: ¿Por qué repites la pregunta?